# Breaking a path into equal segments of a fixed length

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I have an arbitrarily curved path, and want to break it up into segments of fixed length. i.e. I have a squiggle, and want to turn that path into 1-foot segments, plus a remainder portion. How

Answer (score 3):

The `Object → Path → Add Anchor Points` function adds an anchor point in the middle of other anchor points, but you don't have control over the length of segments.

If you know the length of the original path, you could work out how long the segments are. I'm not sure if that helps you in your specific situation though.

Answer (score 2):

Illustrator doesn't contain any CAD related features. You would need to manually measure the sections you want to cut.

Comment: How would you manually measure a curved path?

Comment: Not easily. As I posted, there are no CAD features in Illustrator. This sort of operation is CAD-oriented. You would need to use the Info Panel and record positions, then calculate lengths.

Comment: If you do this a great deal, it may be worthwhile to look into plug ins such as CAD Tools from hotdoor.com or VectorScribe from astutegraphics.com. These offer some additional features to make measuring easier and more intuitive within Illustrator. But neither is CS6 compatible yet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative to add any number of equally spaced vertices to a path, which i prefer to the 'add anchor point' command

[image: add any # of equally spaced vertices]

Answer (score -1):

You should try [CADtools](https://www.hotdoor.com/cadtools) from HotDoor, it's a plugin for Illustrator.

For making equal segment on curve: Use `Path Divider`.